# Enviar datos json con ajax con bearer + token

Tags: ajax

Intento enviar datos json utilizando ajax con bearer + token.

Se genera el json correctamente pero cuando se envia no se obtiene respuesta del servidor.

Utilizo php y netbeans.

```js
function mostrar(){
   
$ajax({
   url: urlservidor,
   method: 'POST',
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   data: array,
   beforeSend: function (xhr) {
       xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer' + token);
    },       
   success: function(response){
       console.log(response);
   },
});
}
```

Comment: Creo que antes de ajax te falta un punto ( $.ajax  ), además faltará un espacio después de Bearer, por ejemplo: xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);

Answer (score 1):

Para usar el método de autentificación 'Bearer auth' usualmente se utiliza un token generado a partir de un usuario y una contraseña los cuales se unen y se codifican en Base64 para obtener el token de acceso o también usando directamente un token ya codificado.

Te muestro a continuación un ejemplo:

```js
// Token simple
const token = 'token here';
// Token generado por usuario y contraseña
const tokenBase64 = btoa('username_here:password_here]');
// Datos de la petición
const data = JSON.stringify({
  var1: 'value',
});

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://httpbin.org/post',
  method: 'post',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  data: data,
  beforeSend(request) {
    request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${tokenBase64}`);
  },
  success(data, text) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  error(request, status, error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```